# 一種のX versus Xの一種

Tags: grammar, particle-の

> 絵画は絵の一種だ。
> A painting is a kind of picture. (given translation)

If I was told to translate the English sentence to Japanese I would have written 絵画は一種の絵だ, since the basic sentence is 絵画は絵だ not 絵画は一種だ.

If I were to translate 絵画は絵の一種だ to English I would say "a painting is of the picture variety"· This sentence sounds a bit more formal but essentially has the same meaning.

Are both Xの一種 and 一種のX grammatically correct? Do they have the same meaning? Do they have the same formality?

Comment: Why do you say "A painting is a kind of picture" in English when the basic sentence is "A painting is a picture" and not "A painting is a kind" then?

Comment: A painting is a picture of a kind とは言わないのね

Comment: @aguijonazo Good point. But I can say that '...is a picture of kind' is wrong. I'm not saying that I think the ordering is weird. I;m just trying to understand if both ways work and if there is a difference. For example I have definitely come across sentences with 種類のX rather than Xの種類.

Comment: @Chocolate Yes, we can say "A painting is a picture of a kind", but I think it sounds a little awkward. You'd have to be very careful with the intonation to make it sound natural. I also feel that it has a slightly derogatory feel to it, as though you like pictures but you think that paintings are a second-class kind of picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Xの一種` is a matter-of-fact phrase that is used to say something is one type of the category X. Considering the fact that の and “of” in English work in the opposite direction, we could see this as the direct equivalent of “a kind of X”.

`一種のX` seems to imply the referenced thing is a somewhat unconventional, or depending on the context, even substandard member of the category X. `ある種のX` also has similar connotations.

Comment: Interesting how the reverse order seems to imply 'substandard' in both languages. Does your answer apply to 種類 as well? I think I normally see this as 種類のX, which is the opposite way round to 一種. If it behaves differently can you think of a reason, or is it something I should just remember and move on?

Comment: @user3856370: No, it doesn’t. `N種類のX` is used to count types of X. Its focus is on the number of types. `一種類のX` simply means that the number of types just happens to be one. So, `絵画は一種類の絵です` sounds weird. If not counted like that, `種類` is usually modified by some adjective or phrase, as in `いろいろな種類のX`. `種` is not usually used in this way (except when it is used as a scientific term to mean “species” of animals or plants). `Xの一種類` would be understood as the same as `Xの一種` but it sounds a bit awkward.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I didn't intend to to have '一' in the sentence. It was a question of  絵画は絵の種類だ versus 絵画は種類の絵だ. Maybe you are saying that 種類 with no modifier in front is weird. I'm afraid I've got a little confused.

Comment: @user3856370: `絵画は種類の絵だ` makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: Fair enough. Then I have a serious failure in my understanding of 種類. Maybe a should ask a separate question.